# Updating year in datetime variable

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

I'm playing around with manipulating a `datetime` variable. I can't seem to find a way to update a `datetime` variable year to the current year.

For example I have

```
2007-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

But I would like that to be

```
2012-12-01 00:00:00.000    (The current year were in)
```

I've been playing with `datediff`, but I can't seem to nail it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2007-01-09T12:34:56'
SELECT @date = DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, @date, GETDATE()), @date)

SELECT @date
```

Comment: Thank you AdaTheDev. Spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

For sql server 2008+

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME='2007-12-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @date=DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,@date,GETDATE()),@date)
```

For sql server 2005

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date='2007-12-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @date=DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,@date,GETDATE()),@date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
select @yourDate = dateadd(year, datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year, @yourDate), @yourDate)
```